# plyr-react ref.current.plyr.on is not a function

Tags: reactjs, use-ref, plyr.js

I'm using react function component and plyr-react version 3.2.1.

getting error **ref.current.plyr.on is not a function**

In 3.1.0 and below version it's working fine

Stackblitz Link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vv9haf

CODE

```
const PlayerView = () => {
const ref = useRef();
 useEffect(() => {
  ref.current.plyr.on("ended", (event) => {
  console.log("ended-event");
 })
}, [])

 return (
 <Plyr
  id="player"
  options={{ ...options, controls }}
  source={src}
  ref={ref}
 />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try it

```
ref?.current?.plyr?.on
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have tried it. Not worked.

Initially the reference gives {source: null}.

Added my sample code, Please  check this link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vv9haf

Comment: ok,I'm trying to suggest another way```ref?.current?.plyr&&ref.current.plyr.on("ended", (event) => { console.log("ended-event")```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion not worked, below code also not worked

if(ref?.current?.plyr && ref.current.plyr.on) {
        ref.current.plyr.on("ended", (event) => { console.log("ended-event")})
 }

Comment: Plyr instance doesn't have native methods: https://github.com/chintan9/plyr-react/issues/443